Difference between sign-in with web3 library using MetaMask and SpruceID SSX tool?
I am making a decentralized attestation dapp with React. I found that SpruceId provides some tools for sign-in with Ethereum (namely, SpruceID SSX). What is the difference with a conventional approach of implementing sign-in using web3 libabry in React? Both of them use MetaMask, so what's the difference and how can SpruceId kit be useful for decentralized id development except for this sign-in function?
